# VB.NET InvokeMember("click") Fail

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have this Problem:  In vb.net (VS-2013, framework 4.0) 
I'm trying to click in a Next Button on a web page fully loaded into a WebBrowser Control, doing this:

```
MyElement.InvokeMember("click")
```

so, maybe you will ask, What is MyElement? Well, MyElement (not Nothing by the way) is this:

```
<a onclick="SearchMain.changePage(2);return false;" class=off>Next</a>
```

Why doesn't works?

a clue: I get this HtmlElementErrorEventArgs description: --->  'SearchMain' is undefined

Note:
I've tried the followings without any solution:

```
1)MyElement.InvokeMember("onclick")
2) MyElement.InvokeMember("click",{2}) 
3) MyElement.InvokeMember("onclick",{2}) 
4) MyElement.InvokeMember("SearchMain") 
5) MyElement.InvokeMember("SearchMain.changePage") 
6) MyElement.InvokeMember("SearchMain.changePage",{2}) 
7) Etc....
```

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us where and when you declare and instantiate `MyElement`.

Comment: Dim links = searchWrapper.GetElementsByTagName("a"). I repeat: Myelement is not nothing. Its value is: <a onclick="SearchMain.changePage(2);return false;" class=off>Next</a>